# Connect to Redshift using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to programatically connect to redshift database. I am using Postgresql driver. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rs_opex As Worksheet
    Set rs_opex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPEX")

    'Declare Variables
    Dim objMyconn As Object
    Dim objMyCmd As Object
    Dim objMyRecordset As Object

    Set objMyconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objMyCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objMyRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

      objMyconn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};" & _
            "SERVER=something;" & _
            "DATABASE=whatever;" & _
            "USER=sawantdr;" & _
            "PORT=1234;" & _
            "PASSWORD=abc1234;" & _
            "Option=0"

        objMyconn.Open


End Sub
```

I get an error saying [image]

I think it might be due to SSL being off. Is there a way to turn on SSL programtically or I am doing something else wrong? Please let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 1):

After hours and hours of trying, I found that Redshift has it's own ODBC connector. It can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-windows.html.
Here is the code:

```
Dim oConn As Object
    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    ' Connection Parameters
    Dim strUsername As String
    Dim strPassword As String
    Dim strServerAddress As String
    Dim strDatabase As String

    ' User:
    strUsername = "***"
    ' Password:
    strPassword = "***"
    ' Server Address:
    strServerAddress = "***"
    ' Database
    strDatabase = "***"

     oConn.Open "Driver={Amazon Redshift (x86)};" & _
            "Server=" & strServerAddress & ";" & _
            "Port=***;" & _
            "Database=***;" & _
            "Uid=" & strUsername & ";" & _
            "Pwd=" & strPassword & ";"
```