# How to query ODBC Amazon Redshift database from MS Access using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, amazon-web-services, ms-access, amazon-redshift

I want to pull data from a redshift database into MS Access.

It feels like something that should be pretty straightforward to figure out, but hours of googling has left me with no answers and no direction.

I have a query written with joins etc all from the same database but different tables and schemas.

I don't need a full working script, I just need somebody to point me in the right direction and give me some conceptual basis for how to approach.

Thanks

Comment: Google "VBA amazon redshift"  - top hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545500/connect-to-redshift-using-excel-vba

Comment: I can make the connection, what I'm trying to do is run an sql query to bring in data from that connection. There must be some conceptual misunderstanding on my part because I can't seem to get anything like that answer I'm looking for

Comment: Then why not say that in your question? - describe *exactly what you tried, including your code*, and explain what happened or didn't happen when you ran that code.  People here will help with specific problems, but no-one really wants to write a tutorial or cover basics which are already covered elsewhere.

Comment: @TimWilliams you're absolutely right. My problem is that I have a connection to the database, and I have working sql, but I can't figure out how to use the connection to run the sql. Every way I try to google it I can't find anything, my question is more meant to point me in the direction of how to ask that question in a way that makes sense.

Comment: People can only help if you provide your code and details of your query, along with a full description of what happens when you run the posted code.  That's how to ask the question in a way that maximizes your chances of getting useful responses. See [ask]